# ScrollView Custom Animation

Tags: android, scrollview

I am trying to create some custom scroll view for a weather application that I am working on the scroll view should scroll automatically  forward and then repeat so I need to know when finish scrolling  and therefore I am using

```
scrollAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "scrollX", position)
scrollAnimator.duration = (speed).toLong()
scrollAnimator.setInterpolator { it }
scrollAnimator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
 override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}
 override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
 override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
 override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) = cb()
})
scrollAnimator.start()
```

the issue is that when I am repeating the animation I should go to x0 smoothly but that is not happening what can I do, you can see that in this video: https://youtu.be/gFfvc4KKLaY